# Google drive 403 while downloading a public file if using downloadable url

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have a public file on Google drive. I can download it, no matter I logged in to my Google account or not.

Lets say I acces the file by using Firefox (no Google account logged in): `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lsXIQkxqRBEbMO86OxHs8C8fET7D4oeo/view?usp=drivesdk`. Then I click Download button and I can get a downloadable URL (by using a feature of Firefox). The URL looks like `https://doc-0c-bk-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/biprk0tlgmbv8qfm4ml0d1hkq455h47t/q99lq27ni0mcgll8uajcb5qjo33kk555/1677934950000/09875493210076435183/02018677302207888173Z/1lsXIQkxqRBEbMO86OxHs8C8fET7D4oeo?e=download&uuid=3ba75ae5-1c7f-42f9-a8e1-edcbd329d77b&nonce=4vb8l3vpv030o&user=02018677302207888173Z&hash=1fs65oofpquerq5cpfhi0c63c62eue8u`.
Then I copy and paste this URL to another browser and I got 403 forbidden.

I don't understand WHY AND HOW Google throw me a 403 error, since the file is completely public.

The reason why I ask this question is: I'm writing an app like IDM using Java (and I cannot download file from Google drive, but It works on normal site)

Please help

Comment: Thats a webview link not a download link

Comment: `https://doc-0c-bk-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/biprk0tlgmbv8qfm4ml0d1hkq455h47t/q99lq27ni0mcgll8uajcb5qjo33kk555/1677934950000/09875493210076435183/02018677302207888173Z/1lsXIQkxqRBEbMO86OxHs8C8fET7D4oeo?e=download&uuid=3ba75ae5-1c7f-42f9-a8e1-edcbd329d77b&nonce=4vb8l3vpv030o&user=02018677302207888173Z&hash=1fs65oofpquerq5cpfhi0c63c62eue8u` this is download link. Did you read my post?

Comment: Do a file.get and get the webContentLink  use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click "Download" Google creates a temporary download link. This download link is only valid for some time. For example it's possible that on the next day this link no longer works and you have to click "Download" again.

It's also possible that Google stores cookies in your browser when clicking "Download". The generated download link will only work in the browser who has these cookies. Meaning a different browser cannot use the temporary link as it doesn't have the matching cookies.

You have to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk) to download a file. [Here is an example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads).

**Update**:

I've clicked on "Download" and saved the link. Then I deleted my browser cookies. After that the link no longer worked. So the temporary download link is bound to cookies. I can say that for sure.

Please also note that temporary links can also be bound to an IP address.

Comment: I need an exact answer, not an assumption. Are you sure about the cookies? Btw i cannot use drive API, my app is like IDM, when user click to Download button on any web page, not only drive, my app will start downloading.

Comment: @SoT I have deleted my cookies and after that the temporary link no longer worked. So I can say for sure that the temporary link uses cookies.